# Is it better to set an enabled state of a button only if it actually changes?

Tags: android

In my first ever Android project I see a lot of code like this:

```
  final boolean lNewButtonState = SOME_CONDITION;
  if (lNewButtonState != mButtonState) {
    mButtonState = lNewButtonState;
    mButton.setEnabled(mButtonState);
  }
```

Does it make any difference to set the state of an `ImageButton` (the type of `mButton`) only if it does change as opposed to setting it always? The button is visible on the screen when the code is executed.

I'd prefer a straightforward (and more readable):

```
  mButton.setEnabled(SOME_CONDITION);
```

The question is, would it impose any drawbacks? Does the answer depend on the Android version (ours is Jelly Bean)?

Comment: the first coded you've posted doesn't make much sense, your ways seems better indeed. maybe you want to set mButtonState too if it's used somewhere else too

Comment: As far as I can see `mButtonState` is only used to keep track of the button state which is wasteful. The field can be eliminated when setting the state without checking the current state (which the android framework does anyway as I learned from @Nima's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter that much because it will be ignored if the button is already enabled. The only cost of it is the `isEnabled()` method call which is pretty insignificant

From Android source code:

```
@Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        if (enabled == isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!enabled) {
            // Hide the soft input if the currently active TextView is disabled
            InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager.peekInstance();
            if (imm != null && imm.isActive(this)) {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

        super.setEnabled(enabled);

        if (enabled) {
            // Make sure IME is updated with current editor info.
            InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager.peekInstance();
            if (imm != null) imm.restartInput(this);
        }

        // Will change text color
        if (mEditor != null) {
            mEditor.invalidateTextDisplayList();
            mEditor.prepareCursorControllers();

            // start or stop the cursor blinking as appropriate
            mEditor.makeBlink();
        }
    }

    @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return (mViewFlags & ENABLED_MASK) == ENABLED;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I'll ask the code next time too :-) You didn't include the Android version in your answer but I double checked this code was already there in Jelly Bean: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.1.1_r1/core/java/android/view/View.java